# How important is my pet and the fish I feed him?

Tags: torchlight-2

Ok, so I have this cute pet that I picked.  It attacks things and I can use fish to make it uber.  The problem I have is that I don't seem to care very much about him, except that his trips to town are very convenient.  What I want to know, in hopes that I will find new appreciation for my pet, is how important he really is to my survival and progress.

Here's the question: **Assuming I give him the best collar and tags I can find, how much of a difference can fish really make?**

I have searched for questions regarding the effects of various fish and therefore understand their various effects, but they don't seem significant.  As a result, I seldom bother to feed fish to my pet.  I've even assigned a hotkey to fish feeding, but still seldom bother.  The problem is probably that I do not know what percentage of my DPS is generated by my pet, and therefore do not account for him whatsoever.  (He is useful but unaccountable.)

Comment: The pet concept is nice, but more of a novelty than anything else.  In the next Torchlight, I hope they ditch the pet in favor of extra character inventory slots and higher stats.  Trips to town can be achieved by a summonable merchant or something else along those lines.  As for fish, I only ever did that in the very beginning of TL1.  After realizing it was completely unnecessary, I stopped and haven't done it once in TL2 and have played through the game several times not once wishing that I had fed my pet some fish.  My pet is always getting wounded and running away anyway.

Comment: At best the pet makes an unreliable extra meat shield.  The strongest builds don't rely on the pet at all.  Think of him as extra inventory space and a courier.

Answer (score 4):

A common use for pets is to teach them spells and have them cast in battle. Summons in particular are very useful as it helps divert enemy damage to temporary minions. I have not seen builds which focus exclusively on making the pets a dps monster. However as an auto-caster the pet can play an important role for a squishy character or one that plays in higher diffculties.